# Can I rename a Print Queue from mcx_0, mcx_1, etc to something more descriptive?

Tags: macos, printing, osx-mountain-lion

I have some printers that are defined in Workgroup Manager in `com.apple.mcxprinting`.

Under `Always > UserPrinterList-Raw` there used to be `mcx_0`, `mcx_1`, etc. dictionaries defining the printers. I recreated them using descriptive names, and they function the same.
[image]

But they still show up as `mcx_...` in `lpoptions` and in at least one application.

The problem, and why I recreated them, is that when printing in Google Chrome the printers show up as `mcx_...`:
[image: Google Chrome dialog showing mcx printer]

Using the System Dialog shows the name defined in `Always > UserPrinterList-Raw > MyDescriptivePrinterName > DisplayName`, but users are generally unaware this dialog exists.

How can I rename these print queues?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to rename those printers via the CUPS-configuration on the server they are delivered from via the workgroup-manager. I can not currently test that but I will try to check that next week.

The question is why you do not use the systems print dialog in chrome as that one displays the correct names. You could map CTRL-P to the "print using system dialog" feature (CTRL-ALT-P)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't receive a notification for this answer. Remapping the print dialog is appealing. How is this done?

Comment: BTW, it wasn't possible to rename them in CUPS. Or, at least I didn't see a way to (I could only edit the description and location).